# Sharepoint calculated if statement not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, calculated-columns

I've done a lot of googling and no solution I've found works for me.
Under the screenshot I have translated what it says.
[image: 1]

`=IF(ISBLANK([ToDate]),"",[ToDate]-[DaysToWarn]`
This only throws an syntax error. I've tried many different solutions but none of which seems to work.
I even built a replica in my test environment to see if that worked, which it did. I'm out of options and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, most likely, is due to the parameter separator. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)) says:

> All example formulas in this topic use commas `","` as the parameter delimiter character. In some countries, the comma is reserved for use as the decimal mark. In such countries, users creating a calculated field must use semi-colons `";"` as the delimiter character.

If I'm correct to assume your localization is Swedish, the decimal separator is `','` (comma), and hence the parameter separator to be used shall be `';'` (semicolon).

```
=IF(ISBLANK([ToDate]); ""; [ToDate]-[DaysToWarn])
```

Comment: Thank you! You have saved me a lot of frustration